# Setting up single sign-on between Mac client & OS X Server

Tags: mac, mac-osx-server, kerberos, single-sign-on, opendirectory

I'm not "single sign-on" is the right terminology for what I'm trying to accomplish, so please correct me if I'm wrong.

We have a Mac OS X Server and Mac clients. Kerberos and Open Directory are running and apparently happy.

I imagine the following scenario, but we're having a hard time making it work: After a user logs into their Mac I'd like them to be able to click on a server name/icon (in the Finder sidebar) and automatically be logged into that machine. Seems simple enough...

But, what happens when users click on the server icon is they are logged in as "Guest" and presented with just the "Public" folder. From here they can click "Connect As…" to authenticate, again, and then see all the share points. Of course they could "Remember this password in my Keychain" but that kind of defeats the purpose of Single Sign-on, in my opinion anyway.

[image]

Some users have local "managed" accounts (on client) bound to their account on the server. Both have same name/pwd. Clients are bound to Network Account Server.

I hope I explained this ok. Anyone know how to make this work or what is wrong with our set up?